# Error sharing base64 image on SocialShare plugin

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, canvas, phonegap-plugins

I'm testing the base64 image sharing of the Social Share Plugin([Git Repo](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)) and I'm having some troubles while doing it. I have the code below to create a canvas from a string and create a data url from the canvas and it works fine, the problem is when I try to share the created base64 using 
the plugin the images goes all black. But if I try any other random base64, like the one on the baseTest variable, It works fine. I'd appreciate any help with this. Thanks in advance.

```js
            function socialShare() {
                var canvas = document.getElementById("receipt");
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

                const messages = [
                  "################################",
                  "Central Jogos",
                  "################################",
                  "Apostador: test",
                  "Valor apostado: R$ 5,00",
                  "Valor de retorno: R$ 6,15",
                  "Data da aposta: 19/02/2017 15:07",
                  "Quantidade de jogos: 1",
                  "--------------------------------",
                  "Vasco X Flamengo",
                  "Empate: 1.23",
                  "10/03/2017 15:30",
                  "================================",
                  "Cambista: Cambista Teste",
                  "Telefone: (82) 9977-8877"
                ];

                context.font = "12px Courier new";

                y = 12;
                for (var i in messages)
                {
                  context.fillText(messages[i], 0, y);
                  y += 18;
                }
                
                /*var baseTest = "data:image/png;base64,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";*/

                
                console.log(context.canvas.toDataURL());
                var base64 = context.canvas.toDataURL();

                alert(base64);

                /*window.plugins.socialsharing.share(
                    null, 
                    'Receipt', 
                    base64, 
                    null
                );*/
            }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="socialShare()">Testar</button>

        <canvas id="receipt" width="230" height="270"></canvas>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is somehow getting converted to `jpeg`, I guess. TRY either, drawing a white background before drawing the text or specifying the MIME Type explicitly.

```js
function socialShare() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("receipt");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
    const messages = [
                  "################################",
                  "Central Jogos",
                  "################################",
                  "Apostador: test",
                  "Valor apostado: R$ 5,00",
                  "Valor de retorno: R$ 6,15",
                  "Data da aposta: 19/02/2017 15:07",
                  "Quantidade de jogos: 1",
                  "--------------------------------",
                  "Vasco X Flamengo",
                  "Empate: 1.23",
                  "10/03/2017 15:30",
                  "================================",
                  "Cambista: Cambista Teste",
                  "Telefone: (82) 9977-8877"
                ];
  
    // draw a white background
    context.fillStyle = "#fff";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
    // draw text
    context.font = "12px Courier new";
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    y = 12;
    messages.forEach(function(e) {
        context.fillText(e, 0, y);
        y += 18;
    });
  
    var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
    // or specify the MIME Type explicitly
    // var base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  
    console.log(base64);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="socialShare()">Testar</button>
<canvas id="receipt" width="230" height="270"></canvas>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot! If It's not too trouble I'd like to know if there's any way for me to pass that 'message' text as a string and set dinamically the canvas height and width. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho Yes, there's a way. Will update the answer to accommodate that when I'm back home :)

Comment: @GuilhermeRamalho [Here You GO](https://jsfiddle.net/ppaobacq/). Feel free to ask me, if you have any trouble understanding the code :)

Comment: Thanks again, man! You've been really cool and patient. I've made a video so you could see the final result. When there's only one football match on the bet receipt the image gets kinda blurry but is totally ok, It's visible anyways. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKuEHptS_XE

Comment: and maybe try `let base64 = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1)` to make it unblur

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to split the base64 image data and the share it.

```javascript
base64Data: img.split(',')[1],
```

and then share the base64data through the plugin.